# Full stack MERN App unable to make POST API calls on AWS EC2 . net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: reactjs, api, amazon-ec2, proxy, mern

I currently trying to run a MERN stack app on an AWS EC2 instance. I am using port 3000 for the application and port 5000 (proxy) for the api.

The app runs find and I'm only using npm run dev for now to start the server as this is in very early stages of development and we just need a working example.

My issue is with LogIn.js, (which uses a jwt token verification method). The API endpoint works locally but on the server the console shows:

POST http://52.50.117.51:5000/api/user/Login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Fetch failed loading: POST "http://52.50.117.51:5000/api/user/Login".

This err-refused to connect whevere the call is made is showing when running 'npm run dev' as it looks like the port is already in use. I then read about reverse proxies and I tried to alter my nginx sites-available file like so after restarting nginx :

```
     server {
     listen 80 default_server;
     server_name _;

     location / {
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }

     location /api/ {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
     }
     }
```

I was also having a CORS error that I managed to resolve and after restarting nginx I was able to log in ! but only once.

(root)index.js

```
      const express = require('express');
      const mongoose = require('mongoose');
      const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
      const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
      const cors = require('cors');
      const path = require('path')


      // INITIALIZE THE APP

      const app = express();

      mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
      mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || `mongodb://localhost:27017/node-react- 
      starter`);



     // IMPORT MODELS
     require('./models/Room');
     require('./models/Building');

      // BODYPARSER MIDDLEWARE
      app.use(bodyParser.json());

      // CORS MIDDLEWARE
      app.use(cors())

      // COOKIEPARSER MODULE
      app.use(cookieParser())

      //IMPORT ROUTES

      const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");
      app.use("/api/user", userRoutes)

      require('./routes/roomRoutes')(app);

      require('./routes/buildingRoutes')(app);

      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      app.use(express.static('client/build'));

      const path = require('path');
      app.get('*', (req,res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
      })
      }

      const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
      app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`app running on port ${PORT}`)
      });
```

/client/src/setupProxy.js

```
      const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

      module.exports = function(app) {
      app.use(proxy('/api/*', { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }))
      }
```

/client/src/components/LogIn.js

```
      import React, {useState} from 'react';

      const LogIn = () => {
      const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
      const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

      const handleSubmit = event => {
      event.preventDefault()
      const requestBody = {
      "email": email,
      "password": password
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(requestBody))
      fetch('http://52.50.117.51:5000/api/user/Login',{
      method: 'POST',
      xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
      })
      .then(function(response){
            //alert(response.json());
           // resolve(response ? JSON.parse(response) : {})
       return response.json()
       }).then(function(body){
       console.log(body.message);
       if (body.message == 'Auth successful') {
       localStorage.setItem("token", body.token);
       }
        window.location = '/';
       })
       }

        return (
          <div className="login-page">
            <div className="login-card">
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <h2>Log in</h2>
                <div>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input
                type='text'
                name='email'
                placeholder='email'
                value={email}
                onChange={ (e) => setEmail(e.target.value) }
                /><br/>
            </div>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input
              type='password'
              name='password'
              placeholder='Password'
              value={password}
              onChange={ (e) => setPassword(e.target.value) }
              /><br/>
            <input type='submit' value='Log In'/>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            )
            }



            export default LogIn;
```

the server is t2.micro running ubuntu and I have altered my security group to allow port 5000 and 3000 (and 80,443, 22)

thanks so much !

Comment: did you get the sollution?

Answer (score -1):

Verify if `52.50.117.51` is your public IP.

You don't need to use a separate `http-proxy-middleware`, you are already listening on port 5000